# mod_wsgi (pid=2179): Target WSGI script '/opt/graphite/conf/graphite.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module

Tags: python, apache, amazon-ec2, mod-wsgi, graphite

I am working on AWS RHEL server.
Getting this error each time I access the webpage(Webpage showing 500).

Error.log:

```
[Sat Jul 09 02:51:12.736533 2016] [:error] [pid 2179] mod_wsgi (pid=2179): Target WSGI script '/opt/graphite/conf/graphite.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Sat Jul 09 02:51:12.736572 2016] [:error] [pid 2179] mod_wsgi (pid=2179): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/graphite/conf/graphite.wsgi.
[Sat Jul 09 02:51:12.736593 2016] [:error] [pid 2179] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sat Jul 09 02:51:12.736612 2016] [:error] [pid 2179]   File "/opt/graphite/conf/graphite.wsgi", line 14, in <module>
[Sat Jul 09 02:51:12.736675 2016] [:error] [pid 2179]     from graphite.logger import log
[Sat Jul 09 02:51:12.736685 2016] [:error] [pid 2179]   File "/opt/graphite/webapp/graphite/logger.py", line 84, in <module>
[Sat Jul 09 02:51:12.736737 2016] [:error] [pid 2179]     log = GraphiteLogger() # import-shared logger instance
[Sat Jul 09 02:51:12.736747 2016] [:error] [pid 2179]   File "/opt/graphite/webapp/graphite/logger.py", line 40, in __init__
[Sat Jul 09 02:51:12.736762 2016] [:error] [pid 2179]     self.infoHandler = Rotater(self.infoLogFile,when="midnight",backupCount=1)
[Sat Jul 09 02:51:12.736769 2016] [:error] [pid 2179]   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/logging/handlers.py", line 169, in __init__
[Sat Jul 09 02:51:12.737041 2016] [:error] [pid 2179]     BaseRotatingHandler.__init__(self, filename, 'a', encoding, delay)
[Sat Jul 09 02:51:12.737056 2016] [:error] [pid 2179]   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/logging/handlers.py", line 64, in __init__
[Sat Jul 09 02:51:12.737073 2016] [:error] [pid 2179]     logging.FileHandler.__init__(self, filename, mode, encoding, delay)
[Sat Jul 09 02:51:12.737081 2016] [:error] [pid 2179]   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 902, in __init__
[Sat Jul 09 02:51:12.737390 2016] [:error] [pid 2179]     StreamHandler.__init__(self, self._open())
[Sat Jul 09 02:51:12.737401 2016] [:error] [pid 2179]   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 925, in _open
[Sat Jul 09 02:51:12.737431 2016] [:error] [pid 2179]     stream = open(self.baseFilename, self.mode)
[Sat Jul 09 02:51:12.737449 2016] [:error] [pid 2179] IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/opt/graphite/storage/log/webapp/info.log'
```

graphite.wsgi:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append('/opt/graphite/webapp')

try:
    from importlib import import_module
except ImportError:
    from django.utils.importlib import import_module

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'graphite.settings')  # noqa

from django.conf import settings
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from graphite.logger import log

application = get_wsgi_application()

try:
import whitenoise
except ImportError:
   whitenoise = False
else:
    # WhiteNoise < 2.0.1 does not support Python 2.6
    if sys.version_info[:2] < (2, 7):
        whitenoise_version = tuple(map(
                int, getattr(whitenoise, '__version__', '0').split('.')))
        if whitenoise_version < (2, 0, 1):
            whitenoise = False

if whitenoise:
    from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise
    application = DjangoWhiteNoise(application)
    prefix = "/".join((settings.URL_PREFIX.strip('/'), 'static'))
    for directory in settings.STATICFILES_DIRS:
        application.add_files(directory, prefix=prefix)
    for app_path in settings.INSTALLED_APPS:
        module = import_module(app_path)
        directory = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(module.__file__), 'static')
        if os.path.isdir(directory):
            application.add_files(directory, prefix=prefix)

# Initializing the search index can be very expensive. The import below
# ensures the index is preloaded before any requests are handed to  the
# process.
log.info("graphite.wsgi - pid %d - reloading search index" % os.getpid())
import graphite.metrics.search  # noqa
```

graphite-vhost.conf(hosting it on port 8080):

```
# This line also needs to be in your server's config.
 LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so

# You need to manually edit this file to fit your needs.
# This configuration assumes the default installation prefix
# of /opt/graphite/, if you installed graphite somewhere else
# you will need to change all the occurances of /opt/graphite/
# in this file to your chosen install location.

<IfModule !wsgi_module.c>
    LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
</IfModule>

# XXX You need to set this up!
# Read http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGISocketPrefix
WSGISocketPrefix /var/run/wsgi
<VirtualHost *:8080>
        ServerName localhost
        DocumentRoot "/opt/graphite/webapp"
        ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/graphite_error.log
#/opt/graphite/storage/log/webapp/error.log
        CustomLog /var/log/httpd/graphite_access.log combined
#/opt/graphite/storage/log/webapp/access.log common

        # I've found that an equal number of processes & threads tends
        # to show the best performance for Graphite (ymmv).
        WSGIDaemonProcess graphite processes=3 threads=5 display name='%{GROUP}' inactivity-timeout=120
        WSGIProcessGroup graphite
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        WSGIImportScript /opt/graphite/conf/graphite.wsgi process-group=graphite application-group=%{GLOBAL}

        # XXX You will need to create this file! There is a graphite.wsgi.example
        # file in this directory that you can safely use, just copy it to graphite.wgsi
        WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/graphite/conf/graphite.wsgi

    # XXX To serve static files, either:
    # django-admin.py collectstatic --noinput --settings=graphite.settings
    # * Install the whitenoise Python package (pip install whitenoise)
    # or
    # * Collect static files in a directory by running:
    #     django-admin.py collectstatic --noinput --settings=graphite.settings
    #   And set an alias to serve static files with Apache:
    Alias /content/ /opt/graphite/webapp/content/
    <Location "/content/">
            SetHandler None
    </Location>

    # XXX In order for the django admin site media to work you
    # must change @DJANGO_ROOT@ to be the path to your django
    # installation, which is probably something like:
    # /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django

    Alias /media/ "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/media/"
    <Location "/media/">
            SetHandler None
    </Location>

    # The graphite.wsgi file has to be accessible by apache. It won't
    # be visible to clients because of the DocumentRoot though.
    <Directory /opt/graphite/conf/>
            Options All
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I have chown /opt/graphite to apache. Still getting this error. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it running by changing SELinux settings. Editing the file /etc/selinux/config:

```
SELINUX=disabled
```